# Animations are not working in Xcode 11 versions in devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11

Recently, I have updated my xcode to xcode11 version everything is fine but animations are not working enter the app. what should be the reason for this, What should i do now?

Comment: Animations are not generally broken in iOS 13 for everyone else. So please explain a bit more, how are the animations setup? whats happenign when they are supposed to be run? are you getting warnings or errors? is the animation just not running, wheres your code? what have you tried? there is simply not enough information here for us to provide you a solution

Comment: I found the solution. one of my teammate stopped animations when developing and forgot to enable the animations. After 1 week we found this problem and changes to enable, Now all the animations working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because in new version presentation style changed so you have to try that

```
    yourVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

And after that you can call your animations.